# GestureRecognizer Blocks with BlockKit Xcode Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks, block, build-error

I'm having an issue with GestureRecognizer and BlocksKit which is giving me a build error.

Basically i want, on a gesture, to run a block. I've copied the code from the documentation here....

http://zwaldowski.github.com/BlocksKit/Documentation/Categories/UIGestureRecognizer(BlocksKit).html

... and so far i've had no success as i receive the same build error each time. I've searched around and cannot find anything with the same issue i'm having so i was hoping someone here could maybe help.

The code im using is...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [UITapGestureRecognizer recognizerWithHandler:^(id sender) {
            NSLog(@"Single tap.");
        } delay:0.18];
```

the error i receive is...

```
/Users/JohnSlater/Desktop/iOS Apps/Flink/flink/ViewController.m:202:91: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(id)' to parameter of type 'BKGestureRecognizerBlock' (aka 'void (^)(UIGestureRecognizer *, UIGestureRecognizerState, CGPoint)')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the parameters of the block in the error message. Your code has one argument, sender. But the block needs a UIGestureRecognizer, a UIGestureRecognizerState and a CGPoint. So, it should look something like

```
[UITapGesture recognizerWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer, UIGestureRecognizerState UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, CGPoint point){
}];
```

Comment: +1 - typedef void(^BKGestureRecognizerBlock)(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint location);

Answer (score 0):

`UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [UITapGestureRecognizer recognizerWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint point )
{
    NSLog(@"Single tap.");
} delay:0.18];`

Will work.
Don't know why, but examples [here](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit/blob/master/BlocksKit/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer+BlocksKit.h) seem to be wrong. BKGestureRecognizerBlock declared [here](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit/blob/master/BlocksKit/BKGlobals.h) with 3 parameters. So your linker is right complaining.